# create php webapi to return xml

Tags: php, xml, api

Sorry for the noob question. I am trying to make a web API which return the API call as string in XML. I have created a script to query the database and display them in XML format. I am using AWS API gateway for authentication. Am I on the right track? My XML generates a response like

```
 <CCTVS>
    <CCTV>
        <ID>1000001</ID>
        <Name>A10UE</Name>
        <X></X> 
        <Y></Y>
        <stat>1</stat>
        <ActivatedDate></ActivatedDate>
        <ImageURL>1000000$0.jpeg</ImageURL>
     </CCTV>
 </CCTVS>
```

when I view source of the page. Is it sufficient for the party who calls the API?

Comment: Basically yes, although we don't know the specifics of the API you are using. However, adding a standard header like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>` would be better.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I've also added this right at the top header('Content-type: text/xml').